# Random spaces added when using strcat

Tags: c, xcode, strcat

I am trying to continuously add char to the end of a string. I am doing this through running this in my main

```
 char String[256];
char alphabets[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
for (int i = 0; i < 257; i++) {

            char newChar = alphabets[indexOfNewChar-1];
            printf("new char = %c\n",newChar);
            strcat(String,&newChar);

            printf("%s\n",String);
}
```

when I ran this pile of code this is printed

    `new char = b
bkhobtj
dfhhai bbdhgfcafgcfi   bbaccfeai   afebaci   aedgdddai   hei   hfedhbi   dabeedbi i   cfhi i   caddbhgbi   i   acfi cehbhcddcahbhbabi   aaadi   hi ffhhccbccfbbfggfdhebgeacecai cefdcdb`

As you can see there are spaces and new lines appearing randomly during the run.
After realising the appearances of these random spaces, I tried to remove the blank spaces with

```
char* removeSpaces(char* input)
{
    int i,j;
    char *output=input;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i<strlen(input); i++,j++)
    {
        if (input[i]!=' ')
            output[j]=input[i];
        else
            j--;
    }
    output[j]=0;
    return output;
}
```

However, this did not really affect the outcome as there were still appearances of blank spaces. How can I remove those blank spaces or better stop them from appearing.
On the side note, the code terminates after 160+ repeats of the for loop. How can I overcome this.

Comment: 1) `char String[256];` --> `char String[256] = "";` or `char String[256]; *String = 0;`

Comment: 2) `i < 257;` --> `i < sizeof(String)-1;`

Comment: 3) `strcat(String,&newChar);` --> `strncat(String, &newChar, 1);`

Comment: Aside: suggest either `char alphabets[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";` or `char alphabets[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";` so a string terminator can be included.

Comment: @Chandrasekaran Dinesh Where is there the definition of the variable indexOfNewCha? Provide a minimum compiled function.

Comment: side note, `for (int i = 0; i < 257; i++)` should be checking for i < 256. The char array "String" is 256 long, with indexes ranging from 0 to 255. your current for loop would access "String" out of bounds for the last round of i when i = 256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`newChar` is a single `char`; `&newChar` is *not* a string.  A string needs a null terminator; `strcat` is looking for one, and concatenating the stray characters it finds until it finds one (although this is undefined behavior, so it could cause the program to crash).